# Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< >' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList< >' c# MongoDB

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, list

```
var testa = await _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart).ToListAsync();
List<ListCartRRModel> cart = testa.ToList();
```

i want to pass the array value from testa into the ListCartRRModel but i dont know how

can you guys show me the right way ?

Comment: What type is testa?

Comment: what do you mean with type ? @DavidL

Comment: I edited my answer and added a third approach @Dadang Firmansyah

Comment: var <--- what is this type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use "Select" in Linq:

```
List<ListCartRRModel> carts = await _cartCollection
   .Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart)
   .Select(t=>new ListCartRRModel{ t.id_cart, ...})
   .ToListAsync<ListCartRRModel>();
```